# Sentry Custom Handler on Uncaught Exceptions

Tags: python, logging, error-handling, sentry

In one of my projects, I am using Sentry as an error tracking system(Python3.5).
It has a pretty cool feature which notifies me when an (uncaught)* exception is thrown.

**uncaught exception**: exception which is not in a try-except block.

When an uncaught exception occurs, I would like to use my own handler but not Sentry's handler.Purpose of this is to log that specific exception to a file or console. Can i do that?

Comment: If you're using `django` it provides built-in logging for files and console 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/

Comment: @Aarif thank you for your answer, I am aware of logging library, but I use Sentry for its interface, I am looking for its handler customization. I found a solution like this, despite the the fact that it did not exactly meet my requirements.
(sys.excepthook = some_method),
on any exception some_method will be called, but i want only for uncaught exceptions

Comment: Pardon me, sys.excepthook only works on uncaught exceptions, so my problem is solved

Comment: you can integrate django's logging with the sentry. take a look 
https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/integrations/logging/

Comment: Thanks again for your reply, but its deprecated. Raven is not used anymore.

Comment: @SonerSay `sys.excepthook` is the correct answer but it gets complicated if you use some web framework involved which has its own notion of "unhandled". Another example is that an unhandled exception in a spawned thread will not invoke `sys.excepthook`.

Comment: Yeah, it gets complicated but can you give me such an example of "web framework" which has its own notion of unhandled. If I do not have any thread, it will not cause any problems, right?

Comment: Every webframework has a concept of errorhandlers. See integrations in the Sentry SDK, for example for Flask. We hook into Flask's own signal to get those errors.

Comment: I am using Django, however what I am looking for is just I would like to use my own handler for uncaught exceptions to report. Sentry overrides it. I wanted to know how, I guess it is done with sys.excepthook

Comment: In Django `sys.excepthook` is not used. You need to listen to the `got_request_exception` signal: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#got-request-exception